# Copying from Maple to Mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax

If I have an expression in a Maple document that I can copy as MathML is it possible to paste this into Mathjax to display on StackExchange?

Thanks.

Comment: Maple has a `latex()` command, if memory serves...

Comment: I use latex() for this purpose.  Often the result needs additional editing, but this is easier than typing the Latex from scratch.

Comment: These both look like the beginnings of good *answers* :-)

Comment: Thanks, a problem I've had is that sometimes when I use the latex() command on, say, a definite integral is that it gives me the solution in latex instead of the integral itself... How do you get around that and get only the expression in Latex?

Comment: @Dirk: your followup comment can make a decent question on the Main site. Our FAQ explicitly allows questions on the use of mathematical software...

Comment: Got the answer actually... Use single quotes ' ' around the expression inside the latex() function and it won't compute the answer. It will just output the expression in latex.

Comment: In Maple, the Int() command is not evaluated, while the int() command will be (if possible).  Other inert commands exist as well, such as Limit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latex () function on the expression and use single quotes latex('expressionhere') to output just the expression itself and not the solution to the expression.